# Javascript (jQuery) - Weird undefined variable

Tags: jquery, variables, undefined

Here is my jQuery function

```
function addEntryDatabase(data){
    var entryId;
    $.ajax({
        url: "model/script_ajout.php",  
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: data
        success: function()
        {

        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('An error occurred while adding adata to the database.');
        }
    });
    return entryId;
}
```

Here is my code

```
/**
 * Creating user in the database
 */
var user_id = addEntryDatabase(data);
console.log(user_id);
```

Here is the console of my web browser (everything is fine, I get my **entryId** value)

[image]

But my console.log of **user_id** give me 'undefinned'.
I can not explain why.

Did somebody know why ?

Comment: You declare `entryId`  without a value (`var entryId;`) and then you return it (`return entryId;`). At no point are you assigning a value to it. The *default value* is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After success, you need to change your `entryId` with the response you get in which you will have the id which you want to log.

````
function addEntryDatabase(data){
    var entryId;
    $.ajax({
        url: "model/script_ajout.php",  
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: data
        success: function()
        {
          entryId= response.data.id ///change your entryId;
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('An error occurred while adding adata to the database.');
        }
    });
    return entryId;
}```
````

Comment: So simple.. thank you !

Comment: welcome.Please accept the solution :)

Comment: If you try to access the result before the AJAX request has completed (or if it errors) the value will still be undefined.

Comment: yeah, it will only give undefined if there is an error.